# Url manager rule preventing from entering into a module

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I am using Yii 1.1.14 and I am getting the problem due to URL manager

In the url manager (in main.php) I have created this rule

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<bookingId:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

This rule is prevent me from entering into the admin module. Whenever i try to enter into the admin module, it shows the page redirecting problem which might be because of soome redirection loop.

But whenever I do the following things, I can successfully enter the admin module:-

1. If I change the `<bookingId:\w+>` to `<bookingId:\d+>` . Changing **w** to **d**
2. If I change `'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<bookingId:\w+>'` to `'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<abc:\w+>/<bookingId:\w+>'` . Adding One more parameter

But both of them change my url to this

```
controller/action?bookingId=adasasd
```

So I wanna ask why this rule is affecting the admin module. is there anything wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify second rule for your module:

```
'<module:(yourModuleName)>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<bookingId:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>'
```

In this rule you can restrict `bookingId` parameter only integer values by specifing `\d+` rule (`<bookingId:\d+>`) if variable can takes only integer values.